# Changing Time Series Dataframe to Array

Tags: python, arrays, time-series

I need the following 'ftse_change' dataframe to be in the format of the 'ts'. I have loaded the ftse_change data as CSV into python, but the 'ts' data is already built into a package that I am loading to run a few models from.
(Screenshots below).

I'm not sure what the difference between the two is to begin with (namely the time series array is something I haven't seen before). And I need to be able to convert the ftse data frame into the second (array) format for it to work in the ML model.

Thanks!

[image: Dataframe from CSV file]

[image: Time Series Array]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming what you want is to extract only the 'Change column' to the format shown in the second screenshot. This is how I would do it.

```py
arr = [[[i]] for i in ftse_change.Change.to_list()]
```

eg:

```
col1 = [1,2,3,4,5]
col2 = [1,2,3,4,5]

ftse_change = pd.DataFrame({"Date":col1, "Change": col2})
ftse_change.head()

    Date    Change
0   1   1
1   2   2
2   3   3
3   4   4
4   5   5
arr = [[[i]] for i in ftse_change.Change.to_list()]
print(arr)
#gives: [[[1]], [[2]], [[3]], [[4]], [[5]]]
```

Comment: This only gives the Change column in the list format. I need it to be in TimeSeries (DataArray) - as seen above the array begins in the second photo.

Comment: you're not exactly very clear on what you want, but Im guessing you want the time stamp adn the change to come together in the list

you can do this instead then:

`[[[i.Date, i.Change]] for i in ftse_change.iloc]`

iterate over every row and extract the column data from each row

Comment: The issue lay within the column values, having '%' as strings that could not be converted to floats!